# Checking color similarity algorithm is too slow

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I'm trying to take a screenshot every 50 ms and remove all colors that are not similar to a color that I've decided in the beginning, but the part of code that check the color of every pixel is too slow, so in the end it do a screenshot almost every 1.5s...
Here is the code:

```
public int upX = 114;
public int upY = 28;
public Size size = new Size(1137,640);
public Color rosa = Color.FromArgb(255, 102, 153);
public int tollerance = 20;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  button1.Enabled = false;
  do{
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot = screenshot();
    deleteColors(bmpScreenshot, rosa);
    picturebox1.image = bmpScreenshot;
    Application.DoEvents();
  } while (true);
}

public Bitmap screenshot() {
  Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
  Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
  gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(upX, upY, 0, 0, size);
  return bmpScreenshot;
}

public void deleteColors(Bitmap bitmap, Color colorToSave) {
  for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++){
      Color c = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
      if (!colorsAreSimilar(c, colorToSave, tollerance)){
        bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.White);
      }
     }
   }
 }

public bool colorsAreSimilar(Color a, Color b, int tollerance) {
  if (Math.Abs(a.R - b.R) < tollerance && Math.Abs(a.G - b.G) < tollerance && Math.Abs(a.B - b.B) < tollerance) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The screenshot part take 17 to 21ms, so it's already too high, but the delete part take 1300ms, so I'd like to fix that before, but... I don't know what i could do to make the code lighter.

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is [`GetPixel` is slow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24701703/1270789).

Comment: I would write it in C++, take screenshot and all, it would be faster. Then make it a dll and just call it from C#. You can use LockBits and write it in C#, but the program would become unsafe, which is generally not a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use [`LockBit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx)? It locks the bitmap in the system memory so you can have raw access to it, which is much faster than using the `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods.

```
var bmp = /* open your bitmap */
// The area you want to work on. In this case the full bitmap
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);
// Obtain a pointer to the data and copy it to a buffer
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
var buffer = new byte[Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
{
    // Here you can edit the buffer
}

// Copy the data back to the bitmap and unlock it
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

You can find another example of how to use it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest not using `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` methods if you're concerned about performance.

Try writing your own `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()`, for example using `BitmapData`:

```
        public static Color GetPixel(Bitmap bmp, int x, int y)
        {
            BitmapData bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            int stride = bitmapData.Stride;
            Color c;
            unsafe
            {
                Byte* ptr = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
                int red = ptr[(x * 3) + y * stride];
                int green = ptr[(x * 3) + y * stride + 1];
                int blue = ptr[(x * 3) + y * stride + 2];
                c = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
            }
            bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            return c;
        }

        public static void SetPixel(Bitmap bmp, int x, int y, Color c)
        {
            BitmapData bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            int stride = bitmapData.Stride;
            unsafe
            {
                Byte* ptr = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
                ptr[(x * 3) + y * stride] = c.R;
                ptr[(x * 3) + y * stride + 1] = c.G;
                ptr[(x * 3) + y * stride + 2] = c.B;
            }
            bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }
```

Comment: Surely this answer is similarly slow since you lock and unlock on each operation