# How to convert a PNG image to grayscale and without losing the transparency C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, png

I want to convert a transparent png image to greyscale without losing its transparency.

The problem is the algorithm that I am using in is converting the transparent part into Black, which some picture with black character wouldn't be shown. To give you an idea.

**Heres the original picture :**

[image]

**Look what happens when I pass it through the algorithm.**

[image]

The algorithm :

```
       public static void ToWhiteBlack(Bitmap original)
    {
        try
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
                {
                    var originalColor = original.GetPixel(i, j);
                    var grayScale = (int) ((originalColor.R*0.3) + (originalColor.G*0.59) + (originalColor.B*0.11));
                    var corEmEscalaDeCinza = Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
                    original.SetPixel(i, j, corEmEscalaDeCinza);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're ignorming the alpha value that determines the transparency.  Just pass it to the new color.

Comment: How would you do that ?

Comment: Use the FromArgb overload that takes four arguments.

Comment: Thanks guy !

It worked.

One of you answer it for me to select as a solution

Comment: You might want to check this out for a more preformant way to alter pixels in an image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701703/c-sharp-faster-alternatives-to-setpixel-and-getpixel-for-bitmaps-for-windows-f

Comment: Even better: Use a ColorMatrix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the alpha value of the original color to get the transparency.  Note that if you have partially transparent pixels that will be passed as well.

```
var corEmEscalaDeCinza = Color.FromArgb(originalColor.A, grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
```