# How to convert a png to greyscale, using Lua?

Tags: lua, png

I know [How to convert a PNG image to grayscale and without losing the transparency on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242964), how to do it on Lua or cpp?

Comment: In the unlikely event that the library you're using doesn't have a built-in filter for this, the formula is trivial. Please show the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

PNG is a compressed format so you can't load that without some sort of library. BMP is significantly easier to load into memory, for example: https://bitbucket.org/itraykov/utils/src/master/io/bmp.lua

Now as for your original question how to convert color to black and white, the easiest way is to use the RGB average:

```
local r, g, b = getColor()
local bw = (r + g + b)/3
setColor(bw, bw, bw)
```

Of course you need to change getColor/setColor depending on the library that you are using. Additional checks are necessary for images with transparency or an alpha channel.

Comment: Most filters don't do equal weights.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/17615963/1216776

Comment: I am using libpng12 on ubuntu, can this code use with that?