# How to properly divide a task of editing bitmap for parallel processing for filter

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapdata

I'm currently in the development phase of a photoconverter program and in the process of developing a blur filter. At the initial stages of prototyping this feature, i devised a algorithm in which I had an accumulator for each color channel and add all the pixels in a radius of the target pixel. Afterwards the program would divide the accum by the amount of pixels read(not counting those offscreen). At first I thought this would be fine but when it started to work, I had the problem of this filter taking an hour to render [with this being the result at the lowest setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5BWZ.jpg). So I opted to utilize parallel processing in C# to make this process much easier and faster to run. With the boost of speed came the cost of the image becoming very glitched out. [Here's the image before,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv7dL.jpg) [and Here's the image afterwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL90E.jpg)

This is the code I wrote for the filter

```
public static DirectBitmap NewBlur (DirectBitmap image, int radius)
        {
            int sectorDiam = 128;
            DirectBitmap newimage = image;
            List<Rectangle> renderSectors = new List<Rectangle>();
            Rectangle rect;
            for (int x = 0; x < (image.Width / sectorDiam); x++)
            {
                int xwidth = sectorDiam;
                for (int y = 0; y < (image.Height / sectorDiam); y++)
                {
                    int yheight = sectorDiam;
                    rect = new Rectangle(x * sectorDiam, y * sectorDiam, xwidth, yheight);
                    renderSectors.Add(rect);
                }
            }
            var Picrect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
            var data = image.Bitmap.LockBits(Picrect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.Bitmap.PixelFormat);
            var depth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(data.PixelFormat) / 8; //bytes per pixel
            var buffer = new byte[data.Width * data.Height * depth];
            Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Parallel.ForEach(renderSectors, sector =>
            {
                BlurSection(buffer, sector, Picrect, radius, image.Width, image.Height, depth);
            }
            );
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, data.Scan0, buffer.Length);
            image.Bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

            return image;
        }
```

And here's the method for each section of the image to be blurred.

```
public static void BlurSection(byte[] buffer, Rectangle blurSector, Rectangle bitmaprect, int radius, int width, int height, int depth)
        {

            int[] Accum = new int[4];
            for (int x = blurSector.X; x < blurSector.Width+ blurSector.X; x++)
            {
                for (int y = blurSector.Y; y < blurSector.Height + blurSector.Y; y++)
                {
                    Accum[0] = 0;
                    Accum[1] = 0;
                    Accum[2] = 0;
                    Accum[3] = 0;

                    for (int i = -radius; i <= radius; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = -radius; j <= radius; j++)
                        {
                            var offset = 0;
                            offset = (((y+j) * width) + (x+i)) * depth;
                            if (bitmaprect.Contains(new Point(x + i, y + j))){
                                Accum[0] += buffer[offset + 0];
                                Accum[1] += buffer[offset + 1];
                                Accum[2] += buffer[offset + 2];
                                Accum[3]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Accum[0] = Accum[0] / Accum[3];
                    if (Accum[0] > 255)
                    {
                        Accum[0] = 255;
                    }
                    Accum[1] = Accum[1] / Accum[3];
                    if (Accum[1] > 255)
                    {
                        Accum[1] = 255;
                    }
                    Accum[2] = Accum[2] / Accum[3];
                    if (Accum[2] > 255)
                    {
                        Accum[2] = 255;
                    }
                    var newoffset = ((y * width) + (x * depth*2));
                    buffer[newoffset + 0] = (byte)Accum[0];
                    buffer[newoffset + 1] = (byte)Accum[1];
                    buffer[newoffset + 2] = (byte)Accum[2];
                }
            }
        }
```

It's also worth noting that I'm using a Bitmap class to make access to pixel data much easier, the "DirectBitmap" you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34801225/15473435. Is there anything that I'm missing or not aware of that's causing this algorithm not to function?

Comment: "*utilize parallel processing* in C# to make this process *much easier*" - I really like you joke... (at least I think you were trying to be humorous there)

Comment: Do you work on a new image, maybe a copy or on the original one?